# How to fix Error in over() : identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE?

Tags: r, maps, r-sp

I am working with the following code, originally written by @Josh O'Brien and adapted by @Neil L. The code is intended to use latitude and longitude coordinates of a given location to generate the correct county name for that row.

```
library(maps)
library(maptools)

latlong2county <- function(pointsDF) { 
        # Prepare SpatialPolygons object with one SpatialPolygon 
        # per county 
        counties <- map('county', fill=TRUE, col="transparent", plot=FALSE) 
        IDs <- sapply(strsplit(counties$names, ":"), function(x) x[1]) 
        counties_sp <- map2SpatialPolygons(counties, IDs=IDs, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat 
               +datum=WGS84")) 
        # Convert pointsDF to a SpatialPoints object 
        pointsSP <- SpatialPoints(pointsDF, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat+datum=WGS84")) 
        # Use 'over' to get _indices_ of the Polygons object containing each point 
        indices <- over(pointsSP, counties_sp) 
        # Return the county names of the Polygons object containing each point 
        countyNames <- sapply(counties_sp@polygons, function(x) x@ID) 
        countyNames[indices] 
} 

# Test the function using points in Wisconsin and Oregon. 
testPoints <- data.frame(x = c(-90, -120), y = c(44, 44)) 

latlong2county(testPoints)
```

When I run that code, I get an error that reads:

```
 Error in over(pointsSP, counties_sp) : identicalCRS(x, y) is not TRUE
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out what the issue is. I have tried solutions for the same error on stack overflow and have not had any luck--I would appreciate any help. Here are the first ten rows for data.

```
structure(list(lon = c(-95.91241468, -90.11001628, -98.30641348, 
-80.72761498, -94.51613158, -72.84020128, -117.1440706, -73.75580388, 
-88.12470008, -71.13771368), lat = c(36.10732598, 32.44879598, 
29.50962608, 35.00136258, 38.88771948, 41.77643578, 33.14457978, 
41.00829888, 43.05468238, 42.37087558), state = c("Oklahoma", 
"Mississippi", "Texas", "North Carolina", "Missouri", "Connecticut", 
"California", "New York", "Wisconsin", "Massachusetts")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You are missing a whitespace in the second `CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")`.

Comment: @Gorka sorry I'm a little confused--after which character should I add a line break?

Comment: As @Gorka pointed out, you need a space between "longlat" and "+datum"...right now you have "+proj=longlat+datum=WGS84" for `pointsSP` and you need "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84" with a space inserted...I just tried this out and it should make the difference and work...

Comment: @Ben thank you so much--it worked! If either you or Gorka want to make your response into an answer I can give you the +50 reputation

Comment: @rogues77 Glad it worked! I give the credit to Gorka, perhaps Gorka will be interested in providing an answer.

Comment: @Ben thank you for your clarification! rogues77 glad it worked!  I will provide an answer, suggesting how could be avoided this issue in such cases.  By the way, I was obtaining a different error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the returned error suggests, the issue is caused because the projections (CRS) of `pointsSP` and `counties_sp` are not identical. In your case, there is a small typo when defining the `pointsSP` spatial object: you need to insert a space between the projection arguments, `"+proj=longlat+datum=WGS84"` -> `"+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"`.

A way to ensure that the second object (pointsSP) uses the same projection as the first object (counties_sp) is to use the `proj4string` function as follows:

```
pointsSP <- SpatialPoints(pointsDF, proj4string = CRS(proj4string(counties_sp)))
```

**Note**:

I was getting a different error to the one detailed by OP. In my case, the code was failing in the following line:

```
pointsSP <- SpatialPoints(pointsDF, proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat+datum=WGS84")) 
#> Error in CRS("+proj=longlat+datum=WGS84") : unknown projection id
```

My guess is that OP is using an older version of the `sp` package, which does not verify if the provided CRS is valid. Then, the execution fails in the line `indices <- over(pointsSP, counties_sp)` as consequence of the explained reason.